# PHP shorthand to skip a variable assignment

Tags: php

I am using this shorthand in a function to set a variable to NULL if it is not set. How can I simply not set it?

```
function createArray($rows){
 $array = array();

 $array['id'] = isset($rows['UnitId']) ? $rows['UnitId'] : NULL ;

}
```

Comment: `if(isset($rows['UnitId'])) {$array['id'] = $rows['UnitID'];}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't set it in the first place

```
function createArray($rows){
 $array = array();

 if(isset($rows['UnitId'])) $array['id'] = $rows['UnitId'];

}
```

Comment: Thanks, was just trying to be fancy I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Would this be too simple for you?

```
if(isset($rows['UnitId'])) { 
    $array['id'] = $rows['UnitId'];
}
```